# switch language button for office 365 collection site

Tags: sharepoint-online

Can anyone help me ? I'm looking for a way to add a switch language button in my site collection  using SharePoint online, I couldn't find any solution! 
Thank you!

Comment: do you want to change the default language or just give an option to change between?

Comment: I want to give the users of the site the option to select   preferred language

Answer (score 1):

Changing the language in which user sees a given site depends on several elements (like [user's display language](https://support.office.com/en-nz/article/Change-your-language-and-region-settings-caa1fccc-bcdb-42f3-9e5b-45957647ffd7) and [site's supported languages](https://support.office.com/en-za/article/Choose-the-languages-you-want-to-make-available-for-a-sites-user-interface-16d3a83c-05ab-4b50-8fbb-ff576a3351e8)). It is a complex code.

As for adding a button, you can use Script Editor:
http://community.bamboosolutions.com/blogs/sharepoint-2013/archive/2013/05/20/how-to-use-script-editor-web-part-in-sharepoint-2013.aspx

For changing the language this looks like a ready solution, but I don't think you can make it into a button:
https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/Change-the-default-003d42c6

Otherwise when you have prepared your code and encounter an error/problem then paste it and Stack will help you.